# erlang, convert list of tuples to json

Tags: json, erlang, jiffy

I have a query in mnesia that returns a list of tuples like this:

```
[{"str", 10}, {"str2", 20}]
```

I want to convert it to json using `jiffy` but it seems `jiffy:encode/1` can't do it. Is there anyway to solve my problem?!

Comment: Why is it that `jiffy:encode/1` doesn't work? Do you get an error?

Comment: Yes! it returns an error!

Comment: So what result do you expect for the example provided?

Comment: @Amin Could you please post the error you get?

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand what you expect but first you should provide right data format:

```
1> L = [{"str", 10}, {"str2", 20}].
[{"str",10},{"str2",20}]
2> jiffy:encode({[{list_to_binary(K), V} || {K, V} <- L]}).
<<"{\"str\":10,\"str2\":20}">>
```

Comment: Why the key shoud be converted to binary?

Comment: @BlackMamba: Because it is a format which `jiffy` requires. If you would use another module you have to use a different format.

Comment: @BlackMamba to distinguish actual strings from lists probably